# Merging two dataframes only at specific times

Tags: python, pandas

I have two excel files that I'm trying to merge into one using `pandas`. The first file is a list of times and dates with a subscriber count for that given time and day. The second file has weather information on an hourly basis. I import both files and the data resembles:

```
df1=

Date                  Count
2010-01-02 09:00:00   15
2010-01-02 10:00:00   8
2010-01-02 11:00:00   9
2010-01-02 12:00:00   11
2010-01-02 13:00:00   8
2010-01-02 14:00:00   10
2010-01-02 15:00:00   8
2010-01-02 16:00:00   6
...

df2 = 

Date                  Temp  Rel_Hum   Pressure  Weather
2010-01-00 09:00:00  -5     93        100.36    Snow,Fog 
2010-01-01 10:00:00  -5     93        100.36    Snow,Fog
2010-01-02 11:00:00  -6.5   91        100       Snow,Fog
2010-01-03 12:00:00  -7     87        89        Snow,Fog
2010-01-04 13:00:00  -7     87        89        Snow,Fog
2010-01-05 14:00:00  -6.7   88        89        Snow,Fog
2010-01-06 15:00:00  -6.5   89        89        Snow,Fog
2010-01-07 16:00:00  -6     88        90        Snow,Fog
2010-01-08 17:00:00  -6     89        89        Snow,Fog
...
```

I only need to weather info for the times that are specified in `df1`, but `df2` contains weather info for a 24 hour period for everyday of that month.

Since `df1` only contains 2 columns, I've modified `df1` to have a `Temp`  `Rel_Hum` `Pressure` and `Weather` column so that it resembles:

```
Date                  Count Temp  Rel_Hum Pressure  Weather
2010-01-02 09:00:00   15    0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 10:00:00   8     0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 11:00:00   9     0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 12:00:00   11    0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 13:00:00   8     0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 14:00:00   10    0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 15:00:00   8     0     0       0         0
2010-01-02 16:00:00   6     0     0       0         0
...
```

I've managed to test the code that I've written for a one month period and the problem that I'm encountering is that it is taking a great deal of time to complete the task. I wanted to know if there was a faster way of going about this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

location = '/home/lukasz/Documents/BUS/HOURLY_DATA.xlsx'
location2 = '/home/lukasz/Documents/BUS/Weather Data/2010-01.xlsx'

df1 = pd.read_excel(location)
df2 = pd.read_excel(location2)

df.Temp = df.Temp.astype(float)
df.Rel_Hum = df.Rel_Hum.astype(float)
df.Pressure = df.Pressure.astype(float)
df.Weather = df.Weather.astype(str)

n = len(df2) - len(df)

for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df['Date'][i])
    for j in range(i, i+n):
        date_object = datetime.strptime(df2['Date/Time'][j], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M') # The date column in df2 is a str 
        if df['Date'][i] == date_object:
            df.set_value(i, 'Temp', df2['Temp'][j])
            df.set_value(i, 'Dew_Point_Temp', df2['Dew_Point_Temp'][j])
            df.set_value(i, 'Rel_Hum', df2['Rel_Hum'][j])
            df.set_value(i, 'Pressure', df2['Pressure'][j])
            df.set_value(i, 'Weather', df2['Weather'][j])

# print(df[:5])

df.to_excel(location, index=False)
```

Comment: You can do something like ```df1=df1.merge(df2, on="Date", how="left")```. For more information you can read - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a combination of `reindex` to get `df2` aligned with `df1`.  Make sure to include parameter `method='ffill'` to forward fill weather information.

Then use `join`

```
df1.join(df2.set_index('Date').reindex(df1.Date, method='ffill'), on='Date')
```

[image]